# How to Use Different Background Colors for Different User Types?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to build a forum-like web site. So here's the deal. There's only one class for all the entries. I'm trying to make a new entry class which works the same as the other one accept for the background-color and it will only effect to usertype=admin. To make the long story short, my idea is that every user's post's background colors to show up as black, but admin's to show up as red. Only problem is, I couldn't make it work. I've tried this already but when I get inside a title where all the entries are, all I see is a blank page.

```html
<?php
if (@$user_type=='admin'){
<div  id="<?=$rowtek->entry_id?>" class="adminentry" >
?>
```

How to make it work properly?

Comment: Do you have a little more code you could share? Ultimately this problem seems like it could be solved with a body class. All posts that need to have a black background might have the class `.post`. Then, when it's an admin add a class to `<body>` of `.admin`. In your style sheet you might have: `.post { background-color: black; }` and `.admin .post { background-color: green; }`.

Comment: I'm not really sure whatelse to share exactly. I believe what I'm trying to do with usertype=admin thing goes wrong somehow. Because all entries work perfectly for everyone. Probablyhat I need to do is to first add "if usertype admin". Then I can easly edit css for that class but it doesn't work, sadly...

Comment: Remove the @ and turn on error reporting. Besides i think you need to do if(isset($user_type) and $user_type=='admin')

Comment: If the list of posts is mixed between normal users and admin, then simply add a class to the post, `<div class="post<?php echo 'admin' === $user_type ? ' admin' : ''; ?>">`. Then your css would be something like: `.post { background-color: black; }` and `.post.admin { background-color: green; }`.

Comment: It works but with some problems. First, it messes up my footer somehow and second, when I logged out, I see admin's background color as black, when I logged in as admin, I see it green. Any idea?

Comment: Hard to have ideas about what's wrong when we don't know any of the details. I simply assumed that `$user_type` was a field in the database. Now it sounds like it's attached to a session as that would explain the admin color being black. I'm guessing `$user_type` is undefined because it probably only gets set up at login. If so, then you need to identify posts in the db as `user` vs `admin`. For the footer, sounds like whatever class you used might have been in use already. Try something else. At the minimum inspect your footer with browser dev tools to see what styles are being applied to it.